# Starting influx client on raspberry pi 3B

Tags: raspberry-pi, influxdb

I installed influx db on a Raspberry Pi 3B (OS: Raspian buster), following these instructions (merely the same):

[Instruction 1](https://simonhearne.com/2020/pi-influx-grafana/)
[Instruction 2](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-influxdb/comment-page-1/?unapproved=55238&moderation-hash=efa4e519a44a9e19be39ac0a701a6a49#comment-55238)

Now on trying to start the `influx` client, I get the following error message:

> bash: /usr/local/bin/influx: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I removed influxdb and went through the installation again with the same outcome. Has anybody some advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those who might stumble over the same problem:

apt apparently links the alias `influx` to the binary `/usr/local/bin/influx`, which for me caused the described error. **However** the "correct" binary `/usr/bin/influx` does, at least in my case, the expected thing: it starts the influxdb client!

To avoid the problem I simply created an alias on `influx` to the correct path.